# How to prove $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp\left\{\int_t ^{t+h}A(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\right\}-I_n}{h}=A(t)$

Tags: limits, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Let $t\mapsto A(t)\in C(\mathbb{R},M_n(\mathbb{R}))$, it seems "obvious" that we should have:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp\left\{\int_t
^{t+h}A(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\right\}-I_n}{h}=A(t)\end{equation}

However, I'm having a hard time finding rigorous proof of this result. I don't even know where to start?

Comment: What is your definition of $\exp(\int^{t+h}_t A(s) ds)$?

Comment: The usual matrix exponential, here the matrix is defined by integrating between $t$ and $t+h$ a matrix where each component is continuous... Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a taylor expansion of $\exp(t)$, since $A$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, we observe $|\int_{t}^{t+h}A(s)ds| \leq \max_{s \in [t,t+h]}\|A(s)\| h < \infty$. Then
\begin{align}
\exp \left \{ {\int_{t}^{t+h}A(s)ds} \right\} = I_n+ {\int_{t}^{t+h}A(s)ds}  + O(h^2)  
\end{align}
Consequently
\begin{align}
\frac{\exp \left \{ {\int_{t}^{t+h}A(s)ds} \right\}  - I_n}{h}  =  \frac{1}{h}{\int_{t}^{t+h}A(s)ds}  + O(h)  
\end{align}
By Fundamental theorem of calculus
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0 }\frac{\exp \left \{ {\int_{t}^{t+h}A(s)ds} \right\}  - I_n}{h}  = \frac{d}{dh}\int_{t}^{t+h}A(s)ds \left |_{h=0} = A(t) \right..
\end{align}

Comment: Beautiful ! Thank you !!!